# OpenMP threads only run on one CPU when used on a QThread. (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, openmp, qthread

I'm trying to write a particle simulation.
I created a worker class where all the computation happens and moved it to a `QThread` using `movetothread()` to keep the GUI responsive (that works).

Now to speed up the calculation I wanted to use openMP in the worker.
The strange thing is, that all the openMP threads seem to run on only one CPU core.
I noticed this because the CPU-usage (around 25% on 4 logical cores) and the time to run the simulation does not change, whether using openMP or not.

When calling `omp_get_num_procs()` in the worker it returns 4 but I observe no speedup. I manually set `num_threads()` to 4 just to be sure but it doesn't help.

The program compiles and the calculation is correct (also when using openMP).

I heard there might be a problem when using `QThread`s and openMP simultaneously. Apparently all threads spawned by openMP only run on the CPU assigned to the QThread the worker is moved to.

I'm using Windows 10 64bit, Qt Creator 3.6.1, Qt 5.6.0 (MSVC 2013, 32bit).
In the `.pro` file I added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp`. Also `LIBS += -fopenmp`.

qmake is:

> qmake.exe ParticleSimulations.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"

Make is:

> mingw32-make.exe in C:\ ...

edit:
I also called 'omp_get_num_threads()' which returned 4. What I'm interested in is whether the threads are running on seperate CPUs or on just one.

edit:
By request here is some of my code (not sure if it helps much)
This is from mainwindow.cpp where the second QThread is created that is responsible for the calculation:

```
    Pot=new LennardJones(sig,eps,mass,acc);
    if (ParticlesTypeID==0)
        Part=new TestParticles(confDia->getTestParticlesID(),L,Duration);
    else if (ParticlesTypeID==1)
        Part=new RandomParticles(n,L,Duration);
    else if (ParticlesTypeID==2)
        Part=new FileParticles(confDia->getValuesFromFile(),L,Duration);

    thread = new QThread;
    Pot->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(Pot, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(Pot, SIGNAL(finished()), Pot, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(CancelClick()), Pot, SLOT(onCancelClick()));
    connect(Pot, SIGNAL(sendProgress(int)), this, SLOT(on_Progress(int)));
    connect(Pot, SIGNAL(sendTime(double)), this, SLOT(on_Time(double)));

    thread->start();
    // Calculation
        Part->setParticleData(Pot->Newton(Part->getParticleData(),Part->gettspan(),Part->getL(),MaxNewtonIterations,MaxSteps,MinSteps));
```

This is where part of the calculation takes place (just as an example). Calling omp_get_num_threads() or omp_get_num_procs() there convinced me that OpenMP is working in principle.

```
void LennardJones::NewtonIteration(Eigen::MatrixXd &ParticleData, Eigen::VectorXd &FirstDer, Eigen::MatrixXd &SecDer, Eigen::VectorXd &GKplus1, Eigen::MatrixXd &GderInvKplus1, Eigen::MatrixXd &temp, int &k, double &deltat, int &maxiterations){
int counter=0;
while(((temp-ParticleData.col(k)).norm() > accuracy) && (counter<maxiterations)){
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            FirstDer=FirstDerivative(ParticleData);
            GKplus1=BuildGKplus1(ParticleData,FirstDer,deltat); 
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            SecDer=SecondDerivative(ParticleData);
            GderInvKplus1=BuildGderInvKplus1(ParticleData,SecDer,deltat);              
        }

    }       
    temp = ParticleData.col(k);
    ParticleData.col(k)=ParticleData.col(k)-GderInvKplus1*GKplus1;
    counter++;
}
```

}

Another code snipplet. Here I try to parallelize a for loop which runs n-times (n is the number of particles so there should be much room for performance gains)

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if(j!=i){
            //Positionsvektoren die in diesem Schritt betrachtet werden
            v1K=ParticleData.block(3*(n+i-1),ParticleData.cols()-2,3,1);
            v2K=ParticleData.block(3*(n+j-1),ParticleData.cols()-2,3,1);
            v1Kplus1=ParticleData.block(3*(n+i-1),ParticleData.cols()-1,3,1);
            v2Kplus1=ParticleData.block(3*(n+j-1),ParticleData.cols()-1,3,1);

            //Distanz r
            rK = (v1K-v2K).norm(); //Distance(v1K,v2K);
            rKplus1 = (v1Kplus1-v2Kplus1).norm();   //Distance(v1Kplus1,v2Kplus1);

            //Großer ausklammerbarer Term in der ersten Ableitung
            tempK=-12*epsilon*(pow(sigma,12)/pow(rK,14) - pow(sigma,6)/pow(rK,8));
            tempKplus1=-12*epsilon*(pow(sigma,12)/pow(rKplus1,14) - pow(sigma,6)/pow(rKplus1,8));

            // Erste Ableitungen
            FirstDerK.segment(3*i-3,3)+=tempK*(v1K-v2K);
            FirstDerKplus1.segment(3*i-3,3)+=tempKplus1*(v1Kplus1-v2Kplus1);


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: I use that here albeit on Fedora Linux 64-bit, and it works fine. I think OpenMP may not be getting linked in correctly? Make a debug build and profile that, then look for `omp` functions in the profile.

Comment: Stop downvoting please, this is a valid question, though it may lack debug effort.

Comment: Also it might make sense to post your code, maybe the OpenMP code itself is wrong. And I think you better call `omp_get_num_threads()` to check the amount of threads created, not `_procs()`.

Comment: I think OpenMP does get linked in correctly because all the OpenMP code works and calculates correct results. What exactly do you mean by "profiling the debug build"?

Comment: OpenMP calls are macros, when there is no OMP available, they turn into a noop. But since the functions return a non-zero number, I think OpenMP is present.

Comment: Do you have access to Intel Parallel Studio? It's free to download. Using that, you can profile the application and observe the dgree of concurrency.

Comment: Is you CPU hyperthreaded? Your code will run in 2 threads max - you only have 2 parallel sections - thus if the CPU has HT and it's on, the 2 threads will get attached to the same physical core.

Comment: Downloading Intel Parallel Studio right now. Yes, my CPU is hyperthreaded. I attached another code snipplet of where I try to parallelize a for loop. So it's not only the 'sections' part. Thanks a lot for your help already!

Comment: SEe my answer below on how it's implemented here (and appears to work :)).

Comment: Any updates on this, did the trick work?

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenMP with `QThread` and they work correctly together. The two major differences to the situation described in the question are:

1) I'm using Linux with GCC6

2) The worker class and the `QThread` class are separate. By that, I mean there is a pure STL/Eigen/whatever, but Qt-free, worker class. Then, there is a wrapper class that inherits from `QObject`, and owns an instance of the worker class. The signal-slot connections are made between the application and the wrapper class, that in turn calls the methods of the worker class.

With such a setup, the concurrency degree equals the core number.

To debug concurrency issues further, I advise to download the free Intel Parallel Studio XE and perform a profile run. Then, you'll be able to observe (a) the concurrency degree and (b) whether OpenMP is being used, since when it is, you can see the _`omp` functions in the profile.

This way, I see 2 threads (main GUI + `QThread` one), and then 12 more (Xeon X5650 HT on) created when the OpenMP-enabled function is being called. Thus, I conclude that the `QThread` thread is separate from the OpenMP ones. I manged to observe it using a mere GDB debugger, by the way, since it outputs a message every time a new thread is created.

Other than that, I see a different set of flags being recommended to use OpenMP: `-fopenmp` and `-lgomp`. So, in your case,

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lgomp
```

Though on GCC5 and GCC6, just the first flag, `-fopenmp`, was enough.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @Squidward1314 Did the proposed solution fix the problem?